# Reading a movie file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, avi

I am trying to read a movie in avi format. But it's giving me the following error:

> > xyloObj = mmreader('1.avi',[1 5]);
> >     ??? Initialization failed. (No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection.)

Error in ==>

```
mmreader.mmreader>mmreader.init at 423
            obj.MMReaderImpl = audiovideo.mmreader(fullName);
```

Error in ==>

```
mmreader.mmreader>mmreader.mmreader at 133
            obj.init(fileName);
```

Kindly help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely source of the error is that you are missing the proper codec required to read the given AVI file. Apparently, this can often happen when using 64-bit versions of MATLAB on 64-bit Windows platforms. There are a number of solutions you can try given in [this technical support documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-62LFUH/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-62LFUH) from the MathWorks.

Answer (score 0):

First, can you play it with another application (such as VLC player, Windows Media Player, QuickTime, etc.) on your computer?

If yes, go to gnovice's link.

If no, go get the [GSpot codec information tool](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) which is very useful for determining which codec you need. Download the codec and make it work with a video player, then Matlab.

Comment: VLC is not the tool to test this. Afaik VLC uses built-in codecs, not the system codecs.

Answer (score 0):

[This pdf](http://inside.mines.edu/~whoff/courses/EGGN512/lectures/Matlab_movies.pdf) explains how to solve your problem. Or just use:

```
vid = aviread('Vid261.avi');
vi = frame2im(vid(1)) ;
```